# Time manipulation: how to merge block time and open time in php?

Tags: php, time

For a single day in calendar, a shop has block time (e.g. holiday) and open time (working hours)

**Block time means: the time is blocked out (i.e. not open, close, grey in calendar)**

**Open time means: the time is open up. (i.e. open. people are able to book you)**

```
Case 1:
Block time: 12:00:00 - 23:59:59
Open time: 7:30:00 - 20:00:00
Actual open time (after merged): 7:30:00 - 12:00:00 

Case 2:
Block: 00:00:00 - 08:00:00
Open: 7:30:00 - 20:00:00
Merge: 8:00:00 - 20:00:00 (open)

case 3:
block: 00:00:00 - 12:00:00
open: 13:00:00 - 20:00:00
merge: 13:00:00 - 20:00:00 (open)

case 4:
block: 00:00:00 - 23:59:59
open: 0
merge: 0 (open)
```

What will be formular here?

Here is an example. I splited Christmas into single day, then merge them one by one in a loop. https://ibb.co/cnR9Yz

Comment: It depends entirely on what you mean by 'merge'. I can't seem to find any correlation between how the combination of `block` + `open` ends up with your merge value. Can you please explain the process? Also sharing what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) would help indicate your intent

Comment: case 3 is definitely inconsistent, the merge time should be the same as the open time as there is no overlap.

Comment: @ObsidianAge. Please have look at the updated question. If not clear, I will explain.

Comment: @Nick Please have look at the updated question. Yes, you are right. I updated the number.

Comment: Hi @kenpeter, was my answer not what you were looking for? If not, can you provide more info to help answer your question?

Comment: @Nick, I think you give me a very good idea. Currently, I am writing about it in code. Basically, I draw 2 boxes to prepresent 2 timeslots, then I simulate when they are cross or not cross, in step by step. i.e. lots of if else statement.

Comment: That's basically what I wrote...

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will do what you want. It produces a merged array of opening hours based on input arrays of block hours and open hours. The only case it doesn't consider is when the block start and finish are completely within opening hours (e.g. open = 08:00:00, start = 09:00:00, finish = 11:00:00, close = 13:00:00). If you need that it shouldn't be too hard to add, but it will produce 2 entries in the `$hours` array for one set of input data, so you'll need to be careful with it.

```
$block_times = array(array('12:00:00', '23:59:59'),
                     array('00:00:00', '08:00:00'),
                     array('00:00:00', '12:00:00'),
                     array('00:00:00', '23:59:59')
                     );
$open_times = array(array('07:30:00', '20:00:00'),
                    array('07:30:00', '20:00:00'),
                    array('13:00:00', '20:00:00'),
                    array()
                    ); 

$hours = array();
foreach ($open_times as $key => $times) {
    // any opening times specified?
    if (count($times) != 2) {
        $hours[] = array();
        continue;
    }
    // any block times specified?
    if (count($block_times[$key]) != 2) {
        $hours[] = $times;
        continue;
    }
    $open = strtotime($times[0]);
    $close = strtotime($times[1]);
    $start = strtotime($block_times[$key][0]);
    $finish = strtotime($block_times[$key][1]);
    // figure out opening time
    if ($open >= $finish) {
        // open time is after block ends. No restriction
        $hours[] = array($times[0], $times[1]);
    }
    elseif ($open >= $start) {
        // can we open at all?
        if ($close <= $finish)
            // no, open and close completely within block
            $hours[] = array();
        else
            // yes, we can open from finish time to close
            $hours[] = array($block_times[$key][1], $times[1]);
    }
    else {
        // open is before start of block
        // need to figure out when we have to close
        if ($close < $start)
            $hours[] = array($times[0], $times[1]);
        else
            $hours[] = array($times[0], $block_times[$key][0]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07:30:00
            [1] => 12:00:00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:00:00
            [1] => 20:00:00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13:00:00
            [1] => 20:00:00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
        )
)
```